# Is there anyway to merge these two queries EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have this two queries

```
var resultTypes = from res in Repo.GetAll<ResultType>()
                            select new
                            {
                                Name = res.DisplayName,
                                Count = 0
                            };

var qry = from res in Repo.GetAll<Result>()
          group res by res.ResultType.DisplayName into g
          select new
          {
              Name = g.Key,
              Count = g.Count()
          };
```

After i get the results i have to merge them into 1 probably using a foreach loop and a new collection of anonymous objects, because apparently anonymous objects are immutable.

Is there anyway i can get the same result using only one query.

In case it's not clear what i want to do. I have a collection of `Results` each of them has a property of type `ResultType`, **i want to count how many results are of a certain type.**

I also have a collection of `ResultType` some of which might not be used by any of the results yet, but i still want to show their name only with 0 elements
Thank you

Comment: Isn't only the second query enough for your?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek sorry i should have specified i have a table of all posibile ResultTypes and there might be 0 of them but i still want to get them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for left join:

```
var query = from rt in Repo.GetAll<ResultType>()
            join rj in Repo.GetAll<Result>() on rt.Id equals rj.ResultType.Id into j
            from r in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { rt, r } by rt.DisplayName into g
            select new {
                Name = g.Key,
                Count = g.Where(x => x.r != null).Count()
            }
```

I used `Id` as join column, you can change it if it should e.g. be `DisplayName`.

Or, if you have a navigation property from `ResultType` to `Results` you could probably just do:

```
var query = from rt in Repo.GetAll<ResultType>()
            select new {
                Name = r.DisplayName,
                Count = g.Results.Count()
            }
```

Comment: Hello thank you, it's working. On the second line it should be rj not red